# MILP if then check statements?

Tags: logic, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose I want to check $\forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\quad x_i\in\mathbb R$ if $-b\leq x_i\leq b$ then $Ax\leq c$ holds (where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)'$ with $'$ being transpose) is there a way to do this in MILP with least number of binary variables (with just one or two (the same variable might suffice for all $i$))?

Can something like this work?

First:

$$((|x_1|\leq b)\wedge(|x_2|\leq b)\wedge\dots\wedge(|x_n|\leq b)) \Longleftrightarrow\delta = 0$$

This can be formulated as:
$$\begin{align}
&-b+M\delta\le x_i\le b+M\delta\\
&\delta \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$

Next we want:
$$\begin{align}
   &\delta=0 \Longrightarrow Ax\leq c
\end{align}$$
This can be written as:
$$\begin{align}
   &Ax+M\delta I_n\le c\\
\end{align}$$
where $I_n$ is identity.

Comment: The horrible truth : 99.9 % have neaver heard this name MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming, I assume). Consider giving a good reference for this technique.

Comment: Your first big-M constraint gives you the inverse (if $|x_i|>b$ for any $i$ then $\delta=1$ but not the "if". All $x_i$ could be small and $\delta$ could be either 0 or 1. For your second part, you want to subtract the $M$ term not add, and you want to replace $I_n$ with a column vector of ones, not a matrix.

Comment: @prubin $M=10^{100}$ and $\delta=1$ and $b=1$ and $x_1=\dots=x_n=0$ is impossible. If $x_1=\dots=x_n=0$ then $\delta=0$ should hold.

Comment: I assume that your first big-M constraint contains a typo (left side should be $-b-M\delta$ rather than $-b+M\delta$). If I'm right, then $\delta=1=b$ makes the constraint $-1-M\le x_i \le 1+M$, which $x_i=0$ satisfies. As it is currently written, $\delta=1$ forces $x_i\ge M-b$. Do you really want $x_i\ge 10^{100} - 1$ when $\delta = 1$?

Comment: @prubin $\delta\neq0$ should put $x_i\not\in[-b,b]$ and the program should be defined for all $x_i\in\mathbb R$. Does program do that? If I change $\delta$ to be $\delta_i$ ($n$ $\delta$'s) then program does needed. With single $\delta$ program undefined when $x_1\in[-b,b]$ and $x_2\not\in[-b,b]$.

Comment: If you want $\delta = 1 \implies \exists i \text{ s.t. } |x_i| > b$, then (a) you will need a separate $\delta_i$ for each $i$ and (b) you will need to accept one of two possible compromises: either $x_i = \pm b$ is legal when $\delta = 1$ or $\delta = 1 \implies |x_i| \ge b + \epsilon$ for some $i$, where $\epsilon > 0$. This is because strict inequalities are not well tolerated by mathematical programs.

Comment: @prubin Possible to look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172439/minimum-number-of-binary-integer-variables-to-handle-and-and-or-cases-in-mix please?

Answer (score 0):

A first approach would be define a binary indicator variable $b_i$ for each $-b\leq x_i\leq c$ and the an inequality of the type $Ax -b \leq \sum_1^n (1-b_i) M 1_n$, where $M$ is large enough and $1_n$ is $n$-dimensional vector of 1s. The relaxation of this approach would be quite bad though.

Comment: I think the same binary variable should suffice for all $i$. Why do we need separate?

Comment: You are correct. We do not need separate. Now I do not know about your optimization problem but why do not solve 2 problems, one with $ −b≤x ≤c$ and $Ax \leq c$, and the other one without these constraints. This is what the branching will do anyways

Comment: I think we need multiple variables.