# Minimum number of binary integer variables to handle $AND$ and $OR$ implications in Mixed Integer Linear Programming?

Tags: logic, linear-programming, integer-programming, extremal-combinatorics, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose I want to have an integer program for handling the cases

1. $(x_1>1)\wedge(x_2>1)\wedge(x_3>1)\wedge\dots\wedge(x_n>1)\implies\delta=1$
2. $(x_1>1)\vee(x_2>1)\vee(x_3>1)\vee\dots\vee(x_n>1)\implies\delta=1$
3. $(x_1>1)\wedge(x_2>1)\wedge(x_3>1)\wedge\dots\wedge(x_n>1)\iff\delta=1$
4. $(x_1>1)\vee(x_2>1)\vee(x_3>1)\vee\dots\vee(x_n>1)\iff\delta=1$

how many number of integer variables are needed to handle case?

Is it possible at least one of them needs at most a constant number of binary variables?

Comment: Are the $x_i$ real-valued or integer-valued?

Comment: @prubin they are real valued.

Comment: Strong inequalities with real valued variables are not typically allowed in math programs (since they result in open feasible regions). With integer variables, $x>1$ is the same as $x\ge 2$, which is why I asked. Are you interested in the case $x_n\ge 1$ etc., or willing to change to $x_n \ge 1+\epsilon$ etc. ($\epsilon$ a small positive constant)?

Answer (score 0):

The following formulations assume that $\delta \in \{0,1\}$ and $u_i$ is an upper bound on $x_i$.

For #1, introduce $n$ binary variables $y_i$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_i - 1 &\le (u_i - 1) y_i &&\text{for $i=1,\dots,n$}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i - n + 1 &\le \delta
\end{align}

For #2, you do not need any additional variables:
$$x_i - 1 \le (u_i - 1) \delta \quad \text{for $i=1,\dots,n$}$$

For #3 and #4, you need to consider @prubin's question about $\epsilon$.